# Check if the operator is continous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a space of polynomials with norm $||{p}||=\int_0^1|p(x)|dx$. Check if $\phi=\int_0^1p'(x)dx$ is continous.

Could someone provide me with a hint which inequlity should I use to estimate the integrals?

Comment: You haven't quite formulated your question correct, I think. I think you mean $\|p\| = \int_0^1 |p(x)| dx$ (note that $x$ is a 'dummy variable' here) and that $\phi = \phi(p) = \int_0^1 p'(x) dx$. Am I correct in thinking this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ \phi$ is not continuous: suppose to the contrary that $ \phi$ is  continuous. Then there is $c>0$ such that

$|\phi(p)| \le c ||p||$  for all $p$.

Hence

(*) $|p(1)-p(0)| \le \int_0^1|p(x)|dx$ for all $p$.

Now take a look at $p_n(x)=x^n$. (*) gives:

$1 \le c * \frac{1}{n+1}$  for all $n$, which is absurd.

Comment: OP asked for a *hint*.

Answer (score 2):

Since the operator $\displaystyle \phi(p) = \int_0^1 p'(x) \, dx$ is linear you can check boundedness. That is whether there is a constant $C$ with the property that
$$ \left| \int_0^1 p'(x) \, dx \right| \le C \int_0^1 |p(x)| \, dx$$ for all polynomials $P$.

To make an educated guess about whether this is true or false you should start looking at specific examples. Try the simplest polynomials you can, e.g. $p(x) = x^2$, $p(x) = x^3$, etc. to get a sense of what is going on.